# Instagram Integration authorization_code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, curl, integration, instagram

I hope someone can help, I am about to intergrate with Instagram, I have followed instructions I have authrorised the app and received code=""

```
curl \-F 'client_id=CLIENT-ID' \
    -F 'client_secret=CLIENT-SECRET' \
    -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
    -F 'redirect_uri=YOUR-REDIRECT-URI' \
    -F 'code=CODE' \https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

I do this curl to get an access token but I can't find anywhere for "authorization_code"

Am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer for future people:

authorization_code is the param.